# Parsing JSON from PHP without 'json_decode' or PEAR's 'Services_JSON'

Tags: php, json

I'm working on a project at school for my data mining class and I want to use the stackoverflow API to obtain the raw data.  I was looking at a little introduction tutorial about using PHP to access it and the first code example wasn't working at all.  The culprit was the json_decode function.  The version of PHP installed on the school server is 5.1.6 and the function only exists >= 5.2.  Searching here I found about using pear but the school's PHP is configured with '--without-pear'

What are my best options for getting around these limitations.  I'd rather not have to switch entirely to a separate language.  Is it possible to make a call to an external function in another language?

The offending line was

```
$response = json_decode(http_inflate(file_get_contents($url)));
```

Comment: you can just grab the needed file from pear and include() it, you don't need to install pear. Also, always read php manual comments for the functions, compat code is often listed by users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install PEAR libraries without using the PEAR installation process.  Just download the file from the PEAR website ([Services_JSON](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/)) and include it manually.

Comment: Thanks.  Thats seems to have solved half the problem. Apparently 'http_inflate' requires pecl_http and I can't seem to figure that one out either.  Can I use extensions without any admin rights the way I used JSON.php?  Theres a lot of files in the folder I downloaded, mostly C.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the JSON support directly from PEAR, it has no dependancies on other PEAR libraries. I believe all you would need is [JSON.php](http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/JSON.phps)

Answer (score 0):

I too was in situation when I wanted to code using JSON but on the server was only PHP v 5.1.6. After couple of hours trying, I found that all I had to do was to simply include [JSON.php](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/download) from my PHP script and slightly alter my AJAX function (originally got it somewhere from the web - not my work).

Here are both files, hope it saves somebody some nerves.

**java.js**

```
var request;

function runAjax (JSONString, phpScript, cfunc) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                request = false;
            }
        }
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = cfunc;
    request.open("POST", phpScript);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
    request.send(JSONString);
}

function smazVzor (id) {
    var JSONObject = new Object;
    JSONObject.id = id;
    JSONString = JSON.stringify(JSONObject);
    runAjax(JSONString, "./ajax/smaz_vzor.php", function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            var JSONObject = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            alert(JSONObject.zprava);
            if (JSONObject.kod == 1) document.location.href = "./index.php";
        }
    });
}
```

**smaz_vzor.php**

```
<?php
    require("../../include/dbconnect.php"); // just some commands for MySQL
    require('../../include/JSON/JSON.php'); // <-- THIS IS IMPORTANT
    $json = new Services_JSON();    // create a new instance of Services_JSON class
    $str_json = file_get_contents('php://input');   // read fiel send by POST method as text
    $decoded = $json->decode($str_json);    // decode JSON string to PHP object

    $sql = "DELETE FROM Obory_vzory WHERE id = '$decoded->id'";
    $response = array();    // create response array
    if (!mysql_query($sql, $pripojeni)) {
        $response['kod'] = 0;
        $response['zprava'] = "Something got wrong.\nError: ".mysql_error();
    } else {
        $response['kod'] = 1;
        $response['zprava'] = "Operation successful.";
    }

    $encoded = $json->encode($response);    // encode array $json to JSON string
    die($encoded);  // send response back to java and end script execution
?>
```